# How to open/embed a modern web Page (HTML 5, CSS3, JavaScript, SWF Flash Animation,) inside Native Java Desktop Application?

Tags: javafx, browser, webview, javafx-webengine

I have to Create a **Java Based Native Desktop Application** that embeds java browser, the browser should support flash.

> Actually, **I have to open a certain webpage inside my java
>   application (jar/exe).**

Currently, I select **JavaFX for the UI**,
I have the design complete.
I used **WebView** but it has not enough feature like a modern browser.
It can not run .swf flash file inside the website.

> **Otherwise**, is there any way to attach the website project(all source files) inside the java project?

*How can I solve this Problem?*

Answer (score 1):

I think https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser is you best bet but I am wondering whether the rquirement of a "modern browser" and "Flash" are not a contradiction in itself.